Dicta of Supreme Court vs. District court decision
Let's say two people litigate over an issue in a US district court. One side produces a relevant dicta from one of the The US Supreme Court cases to support its position while the other side adduces a full fledged court decision on the issue at hand but of a district court different from the one in which the case is heard. Neither of the parties produces any other justification for their position. Who would prevail in a vacuum?

I disagree with the close-votes. This is not an opinion based question. Fundamentally the question is about how the rules of precedent work; "It's unknown which would prevail" is an objective and valid answer.

Neither authority is binding precedent, so it could go either way.  District court decisions are not binding even within the same district.  The judge could find either more persuasive; it's not possible to give a general "in a vacuum" answer.
If the dicta came from a justice who was still sitting on the supreme court, it might have rather more weight, but that and any other specific circumstances tending to lead in one direction or another seem to violate the "in a vacuum" requirement of the question.

Just to add a third, perhaps less likely but still possible, option; the court could find that it is persuaded by neither and reach a different conclusion altogether.

This is in theory correct, but on balance SCOTUS dicta will more often prevail than a U.S. District decision, unless the U.S. District Court decision provides a very solid explanation regarding why the SCOTUS dicta should not apply, e.g., the that old SCOTUS dicta no longer applies because it interpreted a statute that has since been amended in a way material to its ruling, or has been implicitly overruled by later SCOTUS case law.
